# Trouble using ListBox in windows phone

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-7

Xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="List" Margin="8,8,8,8">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="Auto" Height="300">
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Width="Auto" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbEmail" Width="Auto" FontSize="22" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="89" Click="Button_Click_2" Width="138"/>
</ListBox>
```

C#

```
foreach (var item in Expense)
{
    Display data = new Display();
    data.Name = item.Account_Name;
    data.Amount = item.Total;
    this.List.Items.Add(data);
}
```

While the above code executes in windows phone, i get a list box with name and amount in two different lines.
What should i do, to make them display in same line,(name in left and amount in right)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stackpanel` needs the Horizontal orientation

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Height="300">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Width="Auto" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbEmail" Width="Auto" FontSize="22" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Amount}"/>
</StackPanel>
```